# Why is some, not all, of my styling not working on mobile

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've searched the internet high and low here, but cannot find the answer. Basicaly, my styling looks as intended on desktop and tablet view. Some elements stay styled as they should, but most have not in mobile view. I have made sure that I have added `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`in my head tag, and the path to my CSS sheet is correct (as other screen sizes are styled correctly).

I have been able to make the changes I want to in Dev tools (on Firefox), but when I add the same values (in and and out of a media query) they do not appear to do anything as when I save and refresh my page it reverts back to the incorrect styling.

Does anyone know what I can do differently or add to my code to help? Thank you in advance.

EDIT: here is a snippet of my HTML and corresponding CSS

```css
h2 i {
  color: #fafafa;
}

.profile-text {
  padding: 100px;
}

.profile-text p {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.about {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-style: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.photo {
  height: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.contact-info {
  background-color: #c158dc;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fafafa;
}

.contact-info .value {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.value {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row no-gutters">
  <div class="col-md-4 contact-info">
    <div class="photo">
      <img src="assets/images/bratislava-sm.JPG" alt="profile image">
    </div>
    <div class="upper value">
      <p>Amy H</p>
    </div>
    <div class="value">
      <p><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i> text here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="value">
      <p><i class="fas fa-phone-alt"></i> text here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="value">
      <p><i class="fas fa-envelope-open-text"></i> test here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you post the code relating to your media queries?

Comment: @S.Ramjit I have tried putting the same code in '@media (max-width:600px)' and I've tried '@media and screen (max-width:600px)'

Comment: The proper syntax is ```@media screen and (max-width:600px)``` .In your comment ```screen```and ```and``` are mixed up. Also make sure the queries at the bottom of your CSS file

Comment: @S.Ramjit I've written my "normal" CSS for a section, then put the media queries for that bit under it then move onto the next section

Comment: Does any of the CSS you've written below the media queries have the same class names as the CSS in your media query?

Comment: I've used the same class names in order to targe the same elements. But I have been sure not to use the same class names in different sections of my website.

Comment: https://codepen.io/squish9696/pen/RwWVYax  your css works, resize the browser to see it change color. I'd make sure the cache is clear and try moving the media queries to bottom of the css file.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, it's impossible to tell what's going on. Some possible things to check:

- Make sure you're using cachebusting and that your mobile device isn't just showing an old cached version.
- You can apply an obvious style rule to make sure your changes are being applied, like `background: red;`.
- You can use Chrome or Safari's remote device inspection to inspect the page on your mobile device, if it's connected via usb to your computer. Try it at `chrome://inspect`

Answer (score 0):

So after talking to one of my tutors, it turns out that I had opened a media query further up my CSS file, and in my editing I deleted the closing curly brace. All these issues caused by one little }

So if anyone else has the meta tag in and sill struggling, check all your curly braces are closed.